# No data to display in view results tree when browse jtl file

Tags: jmeter

I've a thread group with a single HTTP request.No data to display in request of view results tree and nothing to display in response data of view results tree when try to browse .jtl file.

Used command to run jmeter:

```
> jmeter -n -t d:\sample.jmx -l d:\results.jtl
```

Comment: show your test plan

Answer (score 3):

By default JMeter doesn't store request and response details into .jtl results file. This is by design, JMeter is saving only essential information required to build metrics as saving request and especially response data is causing massive disk IO overhead and may ruin your test. See [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) for details.

You can configure JMeter to produce more verbose results if you need it, add the next lines to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
```

The above configuration switches .jtl file format to XML and tells JMeter to store more data so you will be able to view it using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener or your favorite text/XML editor.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: It works. By the way, _user.properties_ file resides in `/bin` folder of jmeter root.

Answer (score 0):

Run this Command from bin folder path of jmeter:

```js
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.url=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true -n -t filename.jmx -l logfile.jtl
```

Alternate solution:
[image]
Add this in your jmeter.properites file which is inside bin folder